# Digitalocean spaces with Elixir

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elixir

I'm trying to find a aws-client for elixir that can be used with digitalocean spaces.
I tried aws-elixir (since it allowed different endpoint), but I can't find a way to do S3 operations.

I ask,

1. How do I handle S3 bucket from aws-elixir?
2. If aws-elixir doesn't work, What's the best solution for my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aws-elixir does not support S3 unfortunately, but ExAws does. In order to use ExAws, you first need to add these dependencies in your `mix.exs` file:

```
defp deps() do
  [
    {:ex_aws, "~> 2.0"},
    {:ex_aws_s3, "~> 2.0"},
    {:poison, "~> 3.0"},
    {:hackney, "~> 1.9"},
    {:sweet_xml, "~> 0.6"},
  ]
end
```

Note that both `ex_aws` and `ex_aws_s3` need to be added to your dependencies. `hackney` is an HTTP client, `poison` is for JSON parsing, and `sweet_xml` is for XML parsing.

Now that you added the dependencies, next you need to configure S3 to connect to DigitalOcean spaces instead.

Type this into your config.exs file:

```
config :ex_aws, :s3,
  %{
    access_key_id: "access key",
    secret_access_key: "secret key",
    scheme: "https://",
    host: %{"sfo2" => "your-space-name.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com"},
    region: "sfo2"
  }
```

`"access key"` and `"secret key"` need to be replaced with the actual keys you get from DigitalOcean.

Please make sure to replace `"sfo2"` with the actual Spaces region you're using. And of course, put your actual space name instead of `your-space-name`.

Don't forget to run `mix deps.get`, and you're all set.

You can start an `iex` session and verify that all is working, by running `iex -S mix`, and then typing:

```
ExAws.S3.list_objects("bucket") |> ExAws.request!
```